# Angular Datetime Range Picker for Angular having style sheet css

Tags: angular10

Could you please help me for the best datetime range picker for my project which is having the version 10 and stylesheets css?

I have tried the ngbDatepicker but it is not providing the time.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#range

I have also tried ngx date time range picker but it is not comaptible with the css style sheet.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-datetime-range-picker

It is very helpful if you can provide any solution for this.